# Mimicking C# array initializer behaviour using Reflection

Tags: c#, arrays, cil, reflection.emit

Using ILDasm to reverse engineer some C# code, I found out that the compiler uses the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelper.InitializeArray`method to initialize arrays that contain several constant values of primitive types.

Looks like it creates a special structure for each array size in bytes and marks it with `[StructLayout]` attribute. This is pretty straightforward. But then there is a field of that type that contains the actual data. How do I create a field like that in terms of `Reflection.Emit` and fill it with arbitrary bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you use [ModuleBuilder.DefineInitializedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.modulebuilder.defineinitializeddata.aspx) for that.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I've expected.